# OpenMP - Nested for-loop becomes faster when having parallel before outer loop. Why?

Tags: c++, for-loop, nested, openmp, knapsack-problem

I'm currently implementing an dynamic programming algorithm for solving knapsack problems. Therefore my code has two for-loops, an outer and an inner loop.

From the logical point of view I can parallelize the inner for loop since the calculations there are independant from each other. The outer for loop can not be parallelized because of dependancies.

So this was my **first approach**:

```
for(int i=1; i < itemRows; i++){
        int itemsIndex = i-1;
        int itemWeight = integerItems[itemsIndex].weight;
        int itemWorth = integerItems[itemsIndex].worth;

        #pragma omp parallel for if(weightColumns > THRESHOLD)
        for(int c=1; c < weightColumns; c++){
            if(c < itemWeight){
                table[i][c] = table[i-1][c];
            }else{
                int worthOfNotUsingItem = table[i-1][c];
                int worthOfUsingItem = itemWorth + table[i-1][c-itemWeight];
                table[i][c] = worthOfNotUsingItem < worthOfUsingItem ? worthOfUsingItem : worthOfNotUsingItem;
            }
        }
}
```

The code works well, the algorithm solves the problems correctly.
Then I was thinking about optimizing this, since I was not sure how OpenMP's thread management works. I wanted to prevent unnecessary initialization of the threads during each iteration, thus I put an outer parallel block around the outer loop.

**Second approach:**

```
#pragma omp parallel if(weightColumns > THRESHOLD)
{
    for(int i=1; i < itemRows; i++){
        int itemsIndex = i-1;
        int itemWeight = integerItems[itemsIndex].weight;
        int itemWorth = integerItems[itemsIndex].worth;

        #pragma omp for
        for(int c=1; c < weightColumns; c++){
            if(c < itemWeight){
                table[i][c] = table[i-1][c];
            }else{
                int worthOfNotUsingItem = table[i-1][c];
                int worthOfUsingItem = itemWorth + table[i-1][c-itemWeight];
                table[i][c] = worthOfNotUsingItem < worthOfUsingItem ? worthOfUsingItem : worthOfNotUsingItem;
            }
        }
     }
}
```

This has an unwanted side effect: Everything inside the parallel block will now be executed n-times, where n is the number of available cores. I already tried to work with pragmas `single` and `critical` to force the outer for-loop to be executed in one thread, but then I can not calculate the inner loop by multiple threads unless I open a new parallel block (but then there would be no gain in speed). But nevermind, because the good thing is: this does not affect the result. The problems are still solved correctly.

**NOW THE STRANGE THING: The second approach is FASTER than the first one!**

How can this be? I mean, although the outer for-loop is calculated n times (in parallel) and the inner for-loop is distributed n times among n cores it is faster than the first approach which only calculates the outer loop one time and distributes the workload of the inner for-loop evenly.

At first I was thinking: "well yeah, it's probably because of thread management" but then I read that OpenMP pools the instantiated threads which would speak against my assumption. Then I disabled compiler optimization (compiler flag -O0) to check if it has something to do with. But this did not affect the measurement.

Can anybody of you shed more light into this please?

The **measured times** for solving the knapsack-problem containing 7500 items with a max capacity of 45000 (creating a matrix of 7500x45000, which is way over the used THRESHOLD variable in code):

- Approach 1: ~0.88s
- Approach 2: ~0.52s

Thanks in advance,

phineliner

**EDIT**:

Measurement of a more complex problem:
Added 2500 items to the problem (from 7500 to 10000) (more complex problems can't currently be handled because of memory reasons).

- Approach 1: ~1.19s
- Approach 2: ~0.71s

**EDIT2**:
I was mistaken about the compiler optimization. This does not affect measurement. At least I can not reproduce the difference I measured before. I edited the question text according to this.

Comment: How is THRESHOLD define ? The compiler seems to be able to simplify the code in a way with optimization flag. Maybe you should take a look at the assembly generated ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. THRESHOLD is currently just a dummy set to 5000,    but since the max capacity of the problems is 45000 it does not play a role here. The idea behind THRESHOLD is to prevent parallelization for very small problems because it would take longer to instantiate threads than actually solving the problem sequentially.

Yes, you are right, looking at the assembly would be the next step, but maybe there are some OpenMP guru's here who can help anyways?

Comment: In your first approach each thread in the inner loop has to wait for the mast thread to do it's work. In the second approach each thread does the outer work itself and does not have to wait on the master thread. In the first approach the master thread has to wait for the slowest thread from the inner loop before it can do it's work anyway.

Comment: What happens if you do `#pragma omp for nowait`?

Comment: @z boson, this sounds promising. I just checked if the inner for loop of the 2. approach is executed completely for every parent thread or if it still is distributed among the threads only once. Indeed it is only distributed and executed once and only the work of the outer for loop is being duplicated (see [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4aa5a6c79cbdb32b)). Thus your assumtion makes sense and seems to explain the behaviour.

Comment: @z boson, `#pragma omp for nowait` does give a little speedup for both approaches, but does not diminish the difference

Comment: @phineliner, `nowait` should only help on the second approach. It should not make the difference between the approach diminish it should do the opposite.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's first consider what your code is doing. Essentially your code is transforming a matrix (2D array) where the values of the rows depend on the previous row but the values of the columns are independent of other columns.  Let me choose a simpler example of this

```
for(int i=1; i<n; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        a[i*n+j] += a[(i-1)*n+j];
    }
}
```

One way to parallelize this is to swap the loops like this

Method 1:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
    for(int i=1; i<n; i++) {
        a[i*n+j] += a[(i-1)*n+j];
    }
}
```

With this method each thread runs all `n-1` iterations of `i` of the inner loop but only `n/nthreads` iterations of `j`. This effectively processes strips of columns in parallel. However, this method is highly cache unfriendly.

Another possibility is to only parallelize the inner loop.

Method 2:

```
for(int i=1; i<n; i++) {
    #pragma omp parallel for 
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        a[i*n+j] += a[(i-1)*n+j];
    }
}
```

This essentially processes the columns in a single row in parallel but each row sequentially. The values of `i` are only run by the master thread.

Another way to process the columns in parallel but each row sequentially is:

Method 3:

```
#pragma omp parallel
for(int i=1; i<n; i++) {
    #pragma omp for
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        a[i*n+j] += a[(i-1)*n+j];
    }
}
```

In this method, like method 1, each thread runs over all `n-1` iteration over `i`. However, this method has an implicit barrier after the inner loop which causes each thread to pause until all threads have finished a row making this method sequential for each row like method 2.

The best solution is one which processes strips of columns in parallel like method 1 but is still cache friendly. This can be achieved using the `nowait` clause.

Method 4:

```
#pragma omp parallel
for(int i=1; i<n; i++) {
    #pragma omp for nowait
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        a[i*n+j] += a[(i-1)*n+j];
    }
}
```

In my tests the `nowait` clause does not make much difference. This is probably because the load is even (which is why static scheduling is ideal in this case). If the load was less even `nowait` would probably make more of a difference.

Here are the times in seconds for `n=3000` on my my four cores IVB system GCC 4.9.2:

```
method 1: 3.00
method 2: 0.26 
method 3: 0.21
method 4: 0.21
```

This test is probably memory bandwidth bound so I could have chosen a better case using more computation but nevertheless the differences are significant enough. In order to remove a bias due to creating the thread pool I ran one of the methods without timing it first.

It's clear from the timing how un-cache friendly method 1 is. It's also clear method 3 is faster than method 2 and that `nowait` has little effect in this case.

Since method 2 and method 3 both processes columns in a row in parallel but rows sequentially one might expect their timing to be the same. So why do they differ? Let me make some observations:

1. Due to a thread pool the threads are not created and destroyed for each iteration of the outer loop of method 2 so it's not clear to me what the extra overhead is. Note that OpenMP says nothing about a thread pool. This is something that each compiler implements.
2. The only other difference between method 3 and method 2 is that in method 2 only the master thread processes `i` whereas in method  3 each thread processes a private `i`. But this seems too trivially to me to explain the significant difference between the methods because the implicit barrier in method 3 causes them to sync anyway and processing `i` is a matter of an increment and a conditional test.
3. The fact that method 3 is no slower than method 4 which processes whole strips of columns in parallel says the extra overhead in method 2 is all in leaving and entering a parallel region for each iteration of `i`

So my conclusion is that to explain why method 2 is so much slower than method 3 requires looking into the implementation of the thread pool. For GCC which uses pthreads, this could probably be explained by creating a toy model of a thread pool but I don't have enough experience with that yet.

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed, clear and understandable answer. explanation 2. actually sounds quite plausible to me. however, you might be right that this can not be the only reason why method 3 is so much faster than method 2. an additional thought that arose: maybe method 3 profits from distributing the even load in advance instead of distributing it again in every iteration of method 2? might this be possible?

Comment: @phineliner, i'm not sure how to make a test for explanation 2. I could make `i` shared and only increment it in a single region but the test to see if `i<n` still has to be done by each thread. That would be partially like method 2. I guess I should have checked that. But my guess is that after each parallel region the thread pool has to restart (but not recreate) the idle thread and send new parameters to it. With method 3 it does not have to do this. It simply has to see if each thread is finished.

Comment: Very interesting answer. How come openmp implementations does not mention thread pools ? Compilers should provide this kind of information somewhere no ?

Comment: @coincoin, I learned a lot from this question. The fact that OpenMP does not specify a thread pool has convinced me that Method 3 or Method 4 in my answer are the best solution. It's best not to rely on feature that is not specified. The timing also confirms this. Compilers probably do have some documentation for this.

Comment: @Zboson Could you take a look at your answer again. Assuming that 5 years has passed I thought you may have something to add. Personally I do not find your answer very convincing but I have spend a long time with OpenMP trying to figure out this behavior and could not get to a concrete conclusion as well. I was wondering if over the last 5 years you have came across new information that would change your answer or could add more to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple reason is that since you place your `#pragma omp parallel` at a outter scope level (second version), the overhead for calling threads is less consuming.

<del>In other terms, in the first version, you call threads creation in the first loop `itemRows` time whereas in the second version, you call the creation only once.</del>
And I do not know why !

I have tried reproduce a simple example to illustrate that, using 4 threads with HT enabled :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <omp.h>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> v(10000);
    std::generate(v.begin(),  v.end(), []() { static double n{0.0}; return n ++;} );

    double start = omp_get_wtime();

    #pragma omp parallel // version 2
    for (auto& el :  v) 
    {
        double t = el - 1.0;
        // #pragma omp parallel // version 1
        #pragma omp for
        for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i ++)
        {
            el += v[i];
            el-= t;
        }
    }
    double end = omp_get_wtime();

    std::cout << "   wall time : " << end - start << std::endl;
    // for (const auto& el :  v) { std::cout << el << ";"; }

}
```

Comment/uncomment according to the version you want. If you compile with : `-std=c++11 -fopenmp -O2` you should see that the version 2 is faster.

**Demo on Coliru**

<kbd>[Live Version 1](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f740d6c516d22a6)</kbd> `wall time : 0.512144`

<kbd>[Live version 2](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e124b42bfbd3f8ef)</kbd> `wall time : 0.333664`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's what I thought initially and that's why I actually implemented the second approach. But I read somewhere that OpenMP manages threads within a pool, which means that there should not be any trouble by accessing them within each iteration. Unfortunately I can not parallelize the outer for-loop because of dependancies. This would falsify the result.

Comment: There is a difference between accessing the threads in a pool and creating them. See my edited post with a simple example. You should see a difference.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I see what you are trying to tell me. So this means, that on every use of a `parallel` pragma, the threads are created again instead of being taken from a thread pool within openmp?

I could live with that. But there is that negative side effect that with version 2, the outer loop will be calculated by each core (the whole loop, every time, not distributed workload!) see [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3c49a6745ee8fe5). i would like to run through the outer loop with only one thread (like in version 1).

Comment: Exactly every thing that is inside a parallel region will be done by every threads. How is that a negative effect for the computation ? You are duplicating some works indeed but in the end you are beneficial. Why would you need to run it on only one thread ?

Comment: No, the thread are not created again. They are created once in both version. That's the point of a thread pool. You can dump the list of threads using calls in Linux/Windows and see the list of threads and it's static (unless you explicitly change the number of threads in another parallel region).

Comment: Ok so my answer is not good. How do you explain the results then Z boson ?

Comment: Your answer is okay because you still managed to reproduce the OPs results using another test. That's interesting. I think I know why but I'm having troubles explaining it. Basically in the first approach the inner loop has to wait on the master thread each iteration of the outer loop. Whereas in the second approach each thread does not have to wait on the master thread.

Comment: @z boson, thanks for pointing out that the threads are only created once in both approaches.

Comment: @zboson : could you maybe provide an official source from where you know that openMP automatically uses thread pools? I can't find any. And BTW: if you make your comment to an answer I can mark it as correct solution.

Comment: @phineliner, as far as I know OpenMP does not mandate anything about thread pools. But every implementation I have used (GCC, ICC, MSVC) all use thread pools. I'm trying to put together an answer with an example using pthreads. I have not used pthreads in a few years and even then I had little experience with it so it may take some time.