# Matrix multiplication, KIJ order, Parallel version slower than non-parallel

Tags: c++, c, matrix, openmp

I have a school task about paralel programming and I'm having a lot of problems with it.
My task is to create a parallel version of given matrix multiplication code and test its performence (and yes, it has to be in KIJ order):

```
void multiply_matrices_KIJ()
{
    for (int k = 0; k < SIZE; k++)
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
                matrix_r[i][j] += matrix_a[i][k] * matrix_b[k][j];
}
```

This is what I came up with so far:

```
void multiply_matrices_KIJ()
{
    for (int k = 0; k < SIZE; k++)
#pragma omp parallel
    {
#pragma omp for schedule(static, 16)
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
                matrix_r[i][j] += matrix_a[i][k] * matrix_b[k][j];
    }
}
```

And that's where i found something confusing to me. This parallel version of the code is running around 50% slower than non-parallel one. The difference in speed varies only a little bit based on the matrix size (tested SIZE = 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, and various schedule versions - dynamic, static, w/o it at all etc. so far).

Can someone help me understand what am I doing wrong? Is it maybe because I'm using the KIJ order and it won't get any faster using openMP?

## EDIT:

I'm working on a Windows 7 PC, using Visual Studio 2015 Community edition, compiling in Release x86 mode (x64 doesn't help either). My CPU is: Intel Core i5-2520M CPU @ 2,50GHZ (yes, yes it's a laptop, but I'm getting same results on my home I7 PC)

I'm using global arrays:

```
float matrix_a[SIZE][SIZE];    
float matrix_b[SIZE][SIZE];    
float matrix_r[SIZE][SIZE];
```

I'm assigning random (float) values to matrix a and b, matrix r is filled with 0s.

I've tested the code with various matrix sizes so far (128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048 etc.). For some of them it is intended NOT to fit in cache.
My current version of code looks like this:

```
void multiply_matrices_KIJ()
{
#pragma omp parallel 
    {
    for (int k = 0; k < SIZE; k++) {
#pragma omp for schedule(dynamic, 16) nowait
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
                matrix_r[i][j] += matrix_a[i][k] * matrix_b[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

And just to be clear, I know that with different ordering of loops I could get better results but that is the thing - I HAVE TO use KIJ order. My task is to do the KIJ for loops in parallel and check the performence increase. My problem is that I expect(ed) at least a little faster execution (than the one im getting now which it between 5-10% faster at most) even though it's the I loop that is in parallel (can't do that with K loop because I will get incorrect result since it's matrix_r[i][j]).

These are the results I'm getting when using the code shown above (I'm doing calculations hundreds of times and getting the average time):

### SIZE = 128

- Serial version : 0,000608s
- Parallel I, schedule(dynamic, 16): 0,000683s
- Parallel I, schedule(static, 16): 0,000647s
- Parallel J, no schedule:    0,001978s    (this is    where I exected
  way    slower execution)

### SIZE = 256

- Serial version: 0,005787s
- Parallel I, schedule(dynamic, 16): 0,005125s
- Parallel I, schedule(static, 16): 0,004938s
- Parallel J, no schedule:    0,013916s

### SIZE = 1024

- Serial version: 0,930250s
- Parallel I, schedule(dynamic, 16): 0,865750s
- Parallel I, schedule(static, 16): 0,823750s
- Parallel J, no schedule: 1,137000s

Comment: You are declaring the parallel section within the for k loop. That means, at the end of every iteration of that loop, threads must will wait until all of them have completed their iterations, and then they start the next iteration. I would execute the outer loop concurrently, rather than the inner loops

Comment: What are your compile options? Did you compile with `-O3`? What compiler and OS are you using. Why did you set the chunk size?

Comment: How are you allocating the arrays? I guess you're using global/static arrays since the size is too large to fit in the cache and the only way you can use `matrix_r[i][j]` with large arrays is with global/static arrays.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community edition, on Windows 7. I'm using global arrays, and the size of them is meant not to fit in cache.

Comment: My observation is that this kij-OpenMP code is quite a bit faster than the serial  kij version on Visual Studio 2015, Windows 8 (Release mode!).

Comment: Coliru also reports faster execution with OpenMP: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c80135795b3a2a16

Comment: Do you compile in release mode or debug mode? I'm guessing you're using debug mode.

Comment: I do compile in release mode.

Comment: Please add your full code then to the question. Are you compiling in 64-bit mode (MSVC defaults to 32-bit) mode? This should not matter though.  Also when you write a comment you should start it with @user_name so that the person you address sees you have written them e.g. "@Zboson, I do compile in release mode". You don't need to do this if the comment is in your question or answer though.

Answer (score 4):

*Note: This answer is not about how to get the best performance out of your loop order or how to parallelize it because I consider it to be suboptimal due to several reasons. I'll try to give some advice on how to improve the order (and parallelize it) instead.*

**Loop order**

OpenMP is usually used to distribute work over several CPUs. Therefore, you want to maximize the workload of each thread while minimizing the amount of required data and information transfer.

1. You want to execute the outermost loop in parallel instead of the second one. Therefore, you'll want to have one of the `r_matrix` indices as outer loop index in order to avoid race conditions when writing to the result matrix.
2. The next thing is that you want to traverse the matrices in memory storage order (having the faster changing indices as the second not the first subscript index).

You can achieve both with the following loop/index order:

```
for i = 0 to a_rows
  for k = 0 to a_cols
    for j = 0 to b_cols
      r[i][j] = a[i][k]*b[k][j]
```

Where

- `j` changes faster than `i` or `k` and `k` changes faster than `i`.
- `i` is a result matrix subscript and the `i` loop can run parallel

Rearranging your `multiply_matrices_KIJ` in that way gives quite a bit of a performance boost already.

I did some short tests and the code I used to compare the timings is:

```
template<class T>
void mm_kij(T const * const matrix_a, std::size_t const a_rows, 
  std::size_t const a_cols, T const * const matrix_b, std::size_t const b_rows, 
  std::size_t const b_cols, T * const matrix_r)
{
  for (std::size_t k = 0; k < a_cols; k++)
  {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < a_rows; i++)
    {
      for (std::size_t j = 0; j < b_cols; j++)
      {
        matrix_r[i*b_cols + j] += 
          matrix_a[i*a_cols + k] * matrix_b[k*b_cols + j];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

mimicing your `multiply_matrices_KIJ()` function versus

```
template<class T>
void mm_opt(T const * const a_matrix, std::size_t const a_rows, 
  std::size_t const a_cols, T const * const b_matrix, std::size_t const b_rows, 
  std::size_t const b_cols, T * const r_matrix)
{
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < a_rows; ++i)
  { 
    T * const r_row_p = r_matrix + i*b_cols;
    for (std::size_t k = 0; k < a_cols; ++k)
    { 
      auto const a_val = a_matrix[i*a_cols + k];
      T const * const b_row_p = b_matrix + k * b_cols;
      for (std::size_t j = 0; j < b_cols; ++j)
      { 
        r_row_p[j] += a_val * b_row_p[j];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

implementing the above mentioned order.

> Time consumption for multiplication of two **2048x2048** matrices on Intel i5-2500k
>
> - `mm_kij()`: 6.16706s.
> - `mm_opt()`: 2.6567s.

The given order also allows for outer loop parallelization without introducing any race conditions when writing to the result matrix:

```
template<class T>
void mm_opt_par(T const * const a_matrix, std::size_t const a_rows, 
  std::size_t const a_cols, T const * const b_matrix, std::size_t const b_rows, 
  std::size_t const b_cols, T * const r_matrix)
{
#if defined(_OPENMP)
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    auto ar = static_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>(a_rows);
    #pragma omp for schedule(static) nowait
    for (std::ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < ar; ++i)
#else
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < a_rows; ++i)
#endif
    {
      T * const r_row_p = r_matrix + i*b_cols;
      for (std::size_t k = 0; k < b_rows; ++k)
      {
        auto const a_val = a_matrix[i*a_cols + k];
        T const * const b_row_p = b_matrix + k * b_cols;
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < b_cols; ++j)
        {
          r_row_p[j] += a_val * b_row_p[j];
        }
      }
    }
#if defined(_OPENMP)
  }
#endif
}
```

Where each thread writes to an individual result row

> Time consumption for multiplication of two **2048x2048** matrices on Intel i5-2500k (4 OMP threads)
>
> - `mm_kij()`: 6.16706s.
> - `mm_opt()`: 2.6567s.
> - `mm_opt_par()`: 0.968325s.

Not perfect scaling but as a start faster than the serial code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I do get that the code itself would be faster if I used a different loop order but that's the thing - I HAVE TO use KIJ order and check if I get better performence if loops are done in parallel.

Comment: @Hajta, yeah, three upvotes and this answer does not even answer *your* question. There are many answer on SO with better loop orders but your question is about the *KIJ* loop order. Oh and by the way, why does C++ make code so ugly...

Answer (score 1):

OpenMP implementations creates a thread pool (although a thread pool is not mandated by the OpenMP standard every implementation of OpenMP I have seen does this) so that threads don't have to be created and destroyed each time a parallel region is entered. Nevertheless, there is a barrier between each parallel region so that all threads have to sync. There is probably some additional overhead in the fork join model between parallel regions. So even though the threads don't have to be recreated they still have to be initialized between parallel regions.  More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31382775/2542702).

In order to avoid the overhead between entering parallel regions I suggest creating the parallel region on the outermost loop but doing the work sharing on the inner loop over `i` like this:

```
void multiply_matrices_KIJ() {
    #pragma omp parallel
    for (int k = 0; k < SIZE; k++)
        #pragma omp for schedule(static) nowait
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
                matrix_r[i][j] += matrix_a[i][k] * matrix_b[k][j];
}
```

There is an implicit barrier when using `#pragma omp for`. The `nowait` clause removes the barrier.

Also make sure you compile with optimizing. There is little point in comparing performance without optimization enabled. I would use `-O3`.

Answer (score 0):

Always keep in mind that for caching purposes, the most optimal ordering of your loops will be slowest -> fastest. In your case, that means I,K,L order. I would be quite surprised if your serial code is not automatically reordered from KIJ->IKL ordering by your compiler (assuming you have "`-O3`"). However, the compiler cannot do this with your parallel loop because that would break the logic you are declaring within your parallel region.

If you really truly cannot reorder your loops, then your best bet would probably be to rewrite the parallel region to encompass the largest possible loop. If you have OpenMP 4.0, you could also consider utilizing SIMD vectorization across your fastest dimension as well. However, I am still doubtful you will be able to beat your serial code by much because of the aforementioned caching issues inherent in your KIJ ordering...

```
void multiply_matrices_KIJ()
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int k = 0; k < SIZE; k++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            #pragma omp simd
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
                matrix_r[i][j] += matrix_a[i][k] * matrix_b[k][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn’t parallelizing the outermost loop create a race condition? I mean it's possible that `i` and `j` are the same for different threads.

Comment: Also are you really so confident that in the serial case that GCC will reorder the loops? I would like to see this.